# Format multiple authors with iso-authoryear

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I am using `iso-authoryear` which formats multiple authors like

> GASCH, Robert, TWELE, Jochen, 2005.

What I need, is to format all but the first author with the first name followed by the last name. That would be

> GASCH, Robert, Jochen TWELE, 2005.

I already tried `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first/first-last}` which didn't show any effect....

I am stuck on this for days, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post a minimal compilable code example (MWE) to help us help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`biblatex-iso690` does not use the `sortname` format to format the primary name/`labelname`/sort name. That means you have to redefine the three name formats `author`, `editor` and `translator` separately

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=iso-authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{author}{last-first/first-last}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{last-first/first-last}
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{last-first/first-last}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: SIGFRIDSSON, Emma; Ulf RYDE, 1998. Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments. Journal of Computational Chemistry. Vol. 19, no. 4, pp. 377–395. Available from DOI: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.]